# asp.net dropdown postback not working on firefox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, firefox

I am using dropdownlist placed inside ajax tab container.but it doesnt postback even though i have set autopostback property to true.This happens only in firefox and not in IE or chrome.Can any body help me regarding this.I am using ajax toolkit version 4.1.50731.0.

```
 <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer2" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="myTab"
    Height="2200px" ActiveTabIndex="0">
    <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel8" runat="server" HeaderText="Add Transaction">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div>
                <table class="style1">

                    <tr>
                        <td class="style16">
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                        <td align="right" class="style15">
                            Select&#160;News Heading :&#160;&#160;
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                AutoPostBack="True" >
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator12" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1"
                                ErrorMessage="Please Select News Heading" ValidationGroup="a" InitialValue="Select News Heading">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator><asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender
                                    ID="RequiredFieldValidator12_ValidatorCalloutExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True"
                                    TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator12">
                                </asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            &#160;&#160;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style16">
                            &#160;&#160;
                        </td>
                        <td align="right" class="style15">
                            &#160;&#160;
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            &#160;&#160;
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            &#160;&#160;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style16">
                            &#160;&nbsp;
                        </td>
                        <td align="right" class="style15">
                            Select Sub Heading :&#160;
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" OnLoad="DropDownList2_Load">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator14" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownList2"
                                ErrorMessage="Please select sub heading" ValidationGroup="a" InitialValue="Select News Name">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator><asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender
                                    ID="RequiredFieldValidator14_ValidatorCalloutExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True"
                                TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator14">
                            </asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        &#160;&nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:TabPanel>
    </asp:TabContainer>
```

Comment: may be page is not validated. do check for page.IsValid, as you're using required field validators, behind the sceness it will the page.Isvalid

Comment: @ravi:i cant understand what you say..what  required field validators has to do when you are selecting a dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

you do appear to be missing a closing `</table>` and `</div>` tag from your content template.

does adding those fix your problem?

edit

Does your javascript console (e.g. firebug in firefox) give you any javascript errors?

Answer (score 0):

Solution to your problem that I assume is:

> If validation is failing then `DropDownList` won't PostBack, so please try once by disabling the Validators on `DropDownList`.

Some points to note

1. `RequiredFieldValidator` should have `Display="None"` as you are using `ValidatorCalloutExtender`
2. Put `CausesValidation` on the `DropDownList` and `RequiredFieldValidator`
3. It would result in auto triggering the validation on server-side.
4. Check the `Page.IsValid` in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler before proceeding any other code parts.

Comment: @ALL : THANKS FOR INFO BUT I AM USING FREE TEXTBOX DLL WHICH TELLS TO SPECIFY VALIDATE REQUEST TO FALSE IN PAGE DIRECTIVE.WILL THIS BE ONE WHICH PREVENTS POSTBACK

Comment: @sai I don't think so and please try once by commenting out or removing the `RequiredFieldValidator` & any other Validator, to check if its the cause of your problem or something else..

Comment: one more thing check if there is any error in javascript in 'Error Console' in Firefox (shortcut `ctrl +shift+J`, in Error tab)